# function only returning the last item

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why in the following function it returns only the last item?

```
def lem(file):
    lem = ''
    for line in file:
        lem = line.split()[1]
    return lem

print(lem(file))
```

Comment: Because you always change value of lem variable. Change lem to list and append results of line spliting.

Comment: If you wanted only the last item, how would you implement it differently?

Comment: @PeterWood I think his title was misleading.

Comment: I wwant them in as strings not a list

Comment: @gino: it's a single *value*, it cannot be string**s**

Comment: @JonathonReinhart If OP thinks about how to properly implement what they think *shouldn't* be happening, it will help them understand why it *is* happening.

Comment: Off-topic: It's usually a bad idea to reuse the same name for the function and a variable within it (or to reuse a built-in name as a variable), since it shadows access to the original version should you need it (in the former case for recursion, in the latter for using the built-in). If the function must be named `lem` (a problem since it's easily visually confused for the `len` built-in), don't name the return value `lem` too (`retval` is popular generic term); if you're on Python 2, don't name variables `file` (a deprecated but still occasionally used alternative to the `open` function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you only returned one thing (`lem` is being recreated each time). If you want to return more than one thing, either concatenate the strings, return a list, or make it a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator):

```
# Concatenating
def lem(file):
    lem = []
    for line in file:
        lem.append(line.split()[1])
    return ''.join(lem)
    # Returning a list is the same, just omit the ''.join()
# To use when using ''.join, just print the return value
print(lem(file))
# To use when returning a list, loop (as in the generator case below), or print the list itself as in the ''.join case and it will print the list's repr

# Generator
def lem(file):
    for line in file:
        yield line.split()[1]
# To use the generator, either loop and print:
for x in lem(file):
    print(x)
# Or splat the result generator to print if you're using Py3's print
# function (or using from __future__ import print_function on Py2)
print(*lem(file)) # Separates outputs with spaces; sep="\n" to put them on separate lines, sep="" to print them back-to-back, etc.
# Or to print (or assign) them all at once as a single string:
print(''.join(lem(file))) # Change '' to whatever string you want to put between all the outputs
```

In the generator case, you need to loop over the outputs (implicitly as in splatting with `*` or combining with `''.join`, or explicitly with a `for` loop), printing the generator returned directly is mostly useless (it's going to be the `repr` of a general purpose `generator`, something like `<generator object lem at 0xdeadbeef>`).

Answer (score 2):

On each iteration you reassign the value of `lem`.
You need to save it to list (for example) before each iteration.

```
def lem(myfile):
    res = []
    for line in myfile:
        res.append(line.split()[1])
    return ' '.join(res) # joining to string

print(lem(myfile))
```

And stop using built-in names such as `file`.

Comment: And how can it be if i want all the iems?